# Error message on Applescript duplicate and rename

Tags: applescript, duplicates

I use this applescript to Archive episodes to a new location using a smal reference-file "Archived.m4v" which is then renamed to the episodes name.
I keep getting an error message in OSX Yosemite, while under OSX Mavericks it worked perfectly.

error `"The variable NewFile is not defined." number -2753 from "NewFile"`

All questions related to a script like this have the same code, so I'm going nuts here...

```
set TheFile to alias "Video:Tools:Archived.m4v"
set Destination to alias "Video:Archives:WIP - TV Shows:"}
set Source to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder with the tv episodes...")

tell application "Finder"
    set theList to every file of entire contents of Source
    repeat with thisFile in theList
        set {tid, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "."}
        set FileName to (text items 1 thru -2 of (get name of thisFile)) as text
        set NewFile to duplicate TheFile to folder Destination with replacing
        set NewFile's name to (FileName & ".m4v")
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: There's an anomalous "}" in the second line.

Comment: There are [no documented changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_10/RN-10_10.html) in 10.10 that should affect this.  It sounds kinda like `duplicate` is returning before the copy is completed, so it's not returning a valid file reference.  You might try wrapping the inside of the `tell application "Finder"` block in a `considering application responses` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obvious mistake I see is in your duplicate line. Destination is already an alias so it should not have the word "folder" in front of it. I can't test this right now but try removing "folder" and see if that helps.

The only other thing to try if that didn't fix it is to change your last line to...

```
set name of file ((destination as text) & "Archive.m4v") to (FileName & ".m4v")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The problem seems to be in me using a network-drive which has a small delay. When I run the script on the local hdd it works fine.